# Decent present or near future propulsion system for moving around in orbit or changing orbits

Tags: space, space-travel, spaceships, propulsion

For the world I am constructing, I trying to come up with a spacecraft that could be reasonably be built with present or near future technology that could travel around and change orbits relatively quickly. For example, moving from low earth orbit to lunar orbit in hours. Nuclear Thermal Rockets appears to be a good propulsion system, but I wondering if there are other options I missed. Nuclear Pulse propulsion isn't exactly ideal and chemical propulsion appear too slow.
Edit: To clarify, this is about maneuvering and changing orbits around the same planet, not traveling to different planets.

Comment: This is harder than you think, but nuclear thermal is still probably the best option. A nearly perfect brachisticrhone trajectory at 1G is [still going to take 4.5 hours one way](vhttp://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/appmissiontable.php#id--Spaceship_Handbook_Mission_Table). It is also going to take around 120 km/s of delta-v for a round trip(subtracting orbital velocity from half the figure given for a round trip). I'm fairly doubtful that nuclear thermal rockets would even be capable of this given the low thrust to weight ratios. You might actually need nuclear pulse for this.

Comment: Also given the nature of the Earth Lunar gravitational system any drive capable changing orbits as quickly as you have specified should be more than capable of handling Earth/Lunar transfer orbits as well.

Comment: "To clarify, this is about maneuvering and changing orbits around the same planet, not traveling to different planets" - with reactive propulsin there is no difference, all requires delta-v. U may look into nonreactive launch systems and alike, but it will mean necessity of developed in orbit systems - which not necessarly worth it or possible

Comment: @HerbertSnick http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist2.php, probably more than you were bargaining for.

Answer (score 3):

**Tether/Skyhook systems**

First, [I advise you watch this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqwpQarrDwk)

A Skyhook or tether system is broadly what we describe as a "momentum exchange system" in space travel. The concept is simple: a spacecraft is sped up by slowing something else down, however, the thing being slowed down has orders of magnitude more mass than the spacecraft meaning that while the craft is launched at hundreds of meters per second, the speed of the platform/skyhook barely changes. This type of system, when fully integrated around a planet offers an ideal "space infrastructure" or "public transit" system:

- Individual spacecraft don't need to be loaded up with large amounts of propellant making them smaller, cheaper, and lighter
- Spacecraft don't need to carry dangerous nuclear material around which would cause a catastrophe if the ship were to crash into the planet or undergo a similar disaster
- The main disadvantage is that there is reduced flexibility: spacecraft can't just go wherever but are restricted to specific orbits that are determined by the distribution of the skyhook systems. However, for simple Earth or planetary SOI travel, this isn't a problem.
- Tethers can "refuel" by catching spacecraft moving in the opposite way
- Timing would be difficult for human pilots, but with computerized systems, catching tethers and aligning timing schedules becomes much easier

In an Earth-Moon system, you could have multiple levels of tether systems that allow spacecraft to ascend through orbital shells by moving from tether to tether. Similarly, powerful, longer, "express" tethers could be used if someone wants to go straight from LEO to the Moon or similar. Capsule or spacecraft owners would simply pay a small toll to each tether operator that they use and the operators would then use this money to buy fuel for re-boosting and operational costs.

Answer (score 2):

**Electrodynamic propulsion.**

This is real.  It capitalizes on the magnetic field of the earth and the difference in charge between two separated satellite modules.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/kilometer-long-space-tether-tests-fuel-free-propulsion/

> Once the crew triggers the process, TEPCE should separate into two
> identical minisatellites joined by a kilometer-long tether as thick as
> several strands of dental floss. If deployment goes smoothly, the
> mission can observe how the tether interacts with Earth’s magnetic
> field in the ionosphere (where much of the space junk orbits) to
> change the satellites’ velocity and orbit; the results could possibly
> enable future spacecraft to move around while orbiting Earth—without
> having to carry unwieldy chemical propellant.
>
> the electrodynamic tether technology moves thanks to the physical
> laws that govern electric and magnetic fields. A tether in Earth’s
> ionosphere—an upper atmospheric layer filled with charged particles
> such as free electrons and positive ions—can collect electrons at one
> end and emit them at the other, generating an electric current through
> itself. The electrified tether’s interactions with Earth’s magnetic
> field produce an impetus known as the Lorentz force, which pushes on
> the tether in a perpendicular direction.

Electrodynamic propulsion allows the orbiter to tack around, change orbits and do the other things you want, without carrying propellant.  Reactionless drive, yes yes!

Answer (score 1):

There's a pulsed fusion drive - **the Helicity Drive**  that is being worked on at the moment with the specific intention of developing a system that '*in the  medium term system would enable a nuclear cargo cycler from the earth.*

*It would be seven times more efficient than chemical rockets. A chemical rocket would need multiple refuelings to take 100 tons to the moon. This system would be half the weight of one fuel load launch but would be able to take 100 tons to the moon repeatedly.*'* (From the **Next Big Future** website).

Other than that Check out the Winchell Chung's **Atomic rockets site** for a huge list of near term and longer term options. There are literally dozens of possibilities.